# Indesign - findChangeByList Script - "appliedParagraphStyle" for Object

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm working on a data visualisation project. The idea is to translate words from a book into colors depending several variables. We have a online version that works on d3.js http://savereykjavik.github.io/words/index.html - But we would like to make a nice poster. Since we working with 20.000 words, inDesign seemed to be the more appropriate.

1step - Thanks to the "SplitText" script, I divided each word into object.

2step - With "findChangeByList" and "appliedParagraphStyle" I find how to change the font, font size etc of a specific word.

But I would like to change the background of the object, to have an effect similar to the website. I naively tried to replace "appliedParagraphStyle" by "appliedObjectStyle" with a Object style that have a colored background, but obviously, it doesn't work.

text    {findWhat:"hello"}  {appliedParagraphStyle:"test"}  {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false} Find all double returns and replace with single returns.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the settings for your paragraph style so that text us underlined. Then adjust the settings for the underline so that it has color thickness and is moved above the baseline. Adjust thickness and position to simulat a background color effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TextFrame.
He has the height, width (number of words in the text), content (your word), the coordinates relative to the page, fill.